# What would distinguish a plain-text file saved on OS X 10.8 and a plain-text file saved on Windows 8?

Tags: python, windows, text, encoding, osx-mountain-lion

I've written a script in Python that outputs some G-code for a 3D printer in a .bfb format which is essentially a plain-text file with ASCII characters.

However for some reason, only files outputted then saved again with Wordpad on Windows 8 work, where anything saved with Textedit, Sublime Text 2 etc on my mac do not work.

Why would this be the case?

Thanks for your help.

This is the code used to save files from the script:

```
# creates function that writes to output file
writeFile = open(fileName + ".bfb", "w")
```

Comment: Mac vs. Windows line endings

Comment: How do you open the files for reading? Mac follows UNIX and uses `\n`, Windows uses `\r\n` as line separator, but Python normally *translates* these to `\n` for you.

Comment: Files are saved using the code edited into the OP. They can be then simply opened with a text editor if they need to be edited, but I want to be able to not have to. At the moment I have to run the script, then open the files with wordpad on windows 8 and then re-save them.

Comment: I have been using `\n` in my code to produce a new line in the output file.